# Wordpress: Plain <a> links in single-class.php and archive-class.php not working

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, custom-post-type

This seems like it should be super-easy to resolve, but it has me stumped.

All the links on my page added via `get_header()` and `get_footer()` work just fine. The links added via `single-class.php` and `archive-class.php` don't work.

Looking at the source code in Google Chrome, the links appear to be perfectly formed, but when I click on them nothing happens. Here are two examples:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="http://markrummel.com/dev/enzas/classes/culinary-nunnsense-sunday-brunch/" alt="Culinary Nunnsense Sunday Brunch">Class Details</a>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/EnzasItalian" target="_blank">Enjoy More Photos on Our Facebook Page</a>
```

The first one the `href` attribute is populated via `get_permalink()`. The second is hard-coded exactly as it appears above.

The `class` custom post type is added via a plugin I created. The `single-class` and `archive-class` are added via a custom theme I created.

Here are the two live pages:

archive-class.php --> http://markrummel.com/dev/enzas/classes/

single-class.php --> http://markrummel.com/dev/enzas/classes/culinary-nunnsense-sunday-brunch/

There are links a part of the body of other pages added via `template-[template-name]` that work just fine. It seems like it is only the main content area of the pages associated with the `class` custom post type that have broken links.

Any help figuring out what is going on would be most appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is preventing those links from firing. It appears to be coming from this section in scripts.js starting on line 8:

```
$('.class').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

All links that are children/grandchildren of element with class 'class' will become void, which is causing all of your links to fail.

Comment: Thank you so much! I combed through `scripts.js`, but didn't find this. Actually, that was just a dummy function to copy and paste for other click functions. It just so happens that when I added a custom post type `class`, it added the class `class` to the main entry. Thanks again!